# Consuming RSS in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, rss

Does anyone know of a way to consume RSS in MS SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Webservice Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx) in SQL Service Integration Services
Or you could write a SQLCLR stored procedure

Comment: Ouch... was looking for a simple HTTP get to then parse with OPENXML? guess not...

Comment: Looks liek SQL in not going to be the answer. But thanks anyway.